# adding event listener dynamically

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do add an event listener to a dynamically created object

```
var teamDiv = document.createElement("div");
```

obviously, following doesn't work:

```
teamDiv.onDragStart="drag(event)";
```

so I tried this:

```
teamDiv.addEventListener("dragstart",function(event){drag(event);});
```

and

```
var dragFunction = new Function("event","drag(event);");
teamDiv.addEventListener("dragstart", dragFunction);
```

and

```
teamDiv.addEventListener("dragstart", function(teamDiv) {dragObj(teamDiv);});
```

but nothing works. Can anyone help me with this?

thanks in advance,

Dirk

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/dragstart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you remember to a) append the element and b) make it draggable? See this:

```
var teamDiv = document.createElement('div');

// make it draggable
teamDiv.draggable = 'true';

// append it
document.body.appendChild(teamDiv);

function drag(event) {
    alert("You dragged me");
}

// either one of those will work
// teamDiv.addEventListener("dragstart", drag);
// teamDiv.ondragstart = drag;
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZfXa5/1/

Events aren't camel-cased, so `onDragStart` won't work, it has to be `ondragstart`. You should also *really* avoid putting executable code into strings. They will be `eval`-ed, which is just completely unnecessary. `eval` is evil.

Comment: thanks! I think it already worked from start. My problem was... I expected to see the ondragstart attribute in the div tag when inspecting it with the Firefox Inspector.